# Ng-Repeat Not Updating With Array Change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of contacts using ng-repeat (I'm using my controller as vm), that updates when I add a new contact, edit current ones, or delete contacts - but not when I try and filter the list. Here's the ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="contact in vm.contacts | filter:query | orderBy:'firstname' track by contact._id" class="list-item pointer" ng-class="{'dker': contact.selected }" ng-click="vm.selectContact(contact)">
```

Here's my delete function that works:

```
      function deleteContact(contact){
        vm.contacts.splice(vm.contacts.indexOf(contact), 1);
        Stamplay.Object('contact')
          .remove(contact._id, function(err, res) {
            if(err) return console.log(err);
            console.log(res);
          })
        selectOne();
        };
```

Here's my filtering function that isn't updating the ng-repeat list (I've checked that vm.contacts is changing):

```
      function filterContacts(group){
        angular.forEach(vm.contacts, function(contact){
          if(contact.groups){
            if(contact.groups.indexOf(group.groupname) === -1) {
              vm.contacts.splice(vm.contacts.indexOf(contact), 1);
            }
          }
        });
        selectOne();
      };
```

I tried adding $scope.apply() but that just threw an ugly error

Comment: Did you check if your filter function `filterContacts` is running?

Answer (score 0):

The `splice()` method adds/removes items to/from an array, and **returns the removed item(s)**.

See [splice on mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
function filterContacts(group){
        angular.forEach(vm.contacts, function(contact){
          if(contact.groups){
            if(contact.groups.indexOf(group.groupname) === -1) {
              // assign the result to itself
              vm.contacts = vm.contacts.splice(vm.contacts.indexOf(contact), 1);
            }
          }
        });
        selectOne();
      };
```

Comment: The issue is that I want the contacts that don't match removed from the vm.contacts array - which is working - but the ng-repeat list isn't being updated for some reason

Comment: Can you post the controller code ? I think you must assign the array to a $scope variable like this: `$scope.contacts = vm.contacts` and mapping the relative html `ng-repeat="contact in contacts`